# Building a wrappr on top of OneDrive

Tags: .net, microsoft-graph-api

I am building a Wrapper website on top of OneDrive. The main functionalities are
- User login with their Microsoft Account/O365 Account 
- The application should authenticate the user using Microsoft Identity service
- Display their stored photos on the website

The problem I see is, if we need to access OneDrive / Graph / SharePoint API, we have to first register an App on the Azure portal. After which we will get a Client ID and Secret, using which I can call the Microsoft APIs.

Question
Is this app registration mandatory?
How can I have users use my website seamlessly without registering the app?
Is there a better way to do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you might be confusing app registration and user consent. App registration is a one time task that the app developer does in the Azure portal. If this is setup as a multi-tenant application then users can use the app if they (or their tenant admin) consents. User consent is a much faster process where the end user sees a screen basically asking them if your app can access their data. For consumer accounts (like @outlook.com) accounts the user can always consent and then proceed to your app. For organization accounts (school or work) either the end user or their organization IT admin can consent depending on the security settings of that tenant.